# Binding Locale and Properties in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I am working in an application in JavaFX 11.0 that carries some settings for the app in a `Properties` object. Two of its keys (`locale.language` and `locale.country`) defines the current locale of the app, that will be used for `ResourceBundle` later.

Is there any way I can bind the `locale` according to the information of `locale.language` and `locale.country` keys in `settings` ?

```java
public class MySettings {
    private ObjectProperty<Properties> settings = new SimpleObjectProperties<>();
    private ObjectProperty<Locale> locale = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    ... (get*(), set*(), and *Property())
    public void init() {
        // bind 'locale' with ('settings'.locale.{language,country})
    }
}
```

Comment: Since a `Properties` object is not observable you won't be able to watch for it changes.